# Pass array of ANY type from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-activity

I was testing the putExtras() method and it works perfectly well when I set my array with the appropriate key and get it from the called activity using the get method. However, I noticed that it wasn't possible of other types or at least it didn't gave me an option, in case you were wondering what I was talking about here is the code that I am referring to:

```
Bundle b =new Bundle();  
b.putStringArray(key, array);
Intent i =new Intent(context, secondActivity);
i.putExtras(b);
StartActivity(i);
```

and to get the array from another class simply:

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

Notice the "key" string variable here, it is the only thing that will identify the array you are requesting so it has to be the same on both sides.

Now this code works perfectly well however I am trying to pass an array of type File and another one of type Option.

Do you know how I can do it in these cases?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add the language you are programming in to the tags of your question.

Comment: ^ I think it's obvious that it's Java.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of Android you are only allowed to pass primitive types using bundles.  You cannot pass custom objects. So there are many ways of going about this.  One quick and messy solution can be to retrieve the file array as a static variable.  So you can do something like `SomeActivity.fileArray` However, I wouldn't recommend this method, just showing a simple example... Or you can serialize your object as some primitive type (json string) then deserialize it in the activity you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the overloaded version of `Intent.putExtra()` method that accepts `Serializable`. That's possible because `File` implements `Serializable` and Java arrays are serializable too. Then you can get this array using `Intent.getSerializableExtra()` method.

If you want to put `File[]` to `Bundle` you can use `Bundle.putSerializable()` and `Bundle.getSerializable()` methods.

Comment: I tried it out for File it works but type "Option" doesn't. Do you know how this can be done with Option objects?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear, but Option is an object I created myself. I just want to pass it to another activity.

Comment: If you want to pass a custom object to activities using intents you should either make them `Serializable` or `Parcelable`. In your example it means that `Option` must implement one of these interfaces.